# Google Earth Engine fire detection missing bands using GOES-17 FDCF

Tags: google-earth-engine, goes-16

I'm following a tutorial (https://medium.com/google-earth/how-to-generate-wildfire-boundary-maps-with-earth-engine-b38eadc97a38) to create fire perimeters for the Maui wildfires. Everything seems to work for the GOES 18 data set, but for GOES 17 I'm getting this error "*Error
ImageCollection.getRegion: No bands in collection.*"

```
// Time and location of the fire.
var kincade = {
longitude: -156.35148732346414,
latitude: 20.792893439694705,
start: '2023-8-7',
end: '2023-8-15',
};
// Region of interest.
var radius_of_interest_meters = 45000;
var area_of_interest = ee.Geometry.Point([kincade.longitude, kincade.latitude])
.buffer(radius_of_interest_meters);
// Satellite data.
var goes_17_data = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/GOES/17/FDCF")
.filterDate(kincade.start, kincade.end)
.filterBounds(area_of_interest);
var goes_18_data = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GOES/18/FDCF')
.filterDate(kincade.start, kincade.end)
.filterBounds(area_of_interest);

// Conversion from mask codes to confidence values.
var fire_mask_codes = [10, 30, 11, 31, 12, 32, 13, 33, 14, 34, 15, 35];
var confidence_values = [1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1];
var default_confidence_value = 0;
var map_from_mask_codes_to_confidence_values = function(image) {
return image
.clip(area_of_interest)
.remap(fire_mask_codes, confidence_values, default_confidence_value);
};
var goes_17_confidence = goes_17_data
.select(['Mask'])
.map(map_from_mask_codes_to_confidence_values);
var goes_18_confidence = goes_18_data
.select(['Mask'])
.map(map_from_mask_codes_to_confidence_values);

var goes_17_max_confidence = goes_17_confidence
.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var goes_18_max_confidence = goes_18_confidence
.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

var affected_area_palette = ['white', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple'];
Map.centerObject(area_of_interest, 9);
Map.addLayer(area_of_interest,
{color: 'green'},
'Area of interest', true, 0.2);
Map.addLayer(goes_17_max_confidence,
{opacity: 0.3, min: 0, max: 1, palette: affected_area_palette},
'GOES 17 maximum confidence');
Map.addLayer(goes_18_max_confidence,
{opacity: 0.3, min: 0, max: 1, palette: affected_area_palette},
'GOES 18 maximum confidence');

var combined_confidence = ee.ImageCollection([goes_17_max_confidence,
goes_18_max_confidence])
.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
Map.addLayer(combined_confidence,
{opacity: 0.3, min: 0, max: 1, palette: affected_area_palette},
'Combined confidence');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind the error message is the absence of images in the image collection. Since there is no image, there is no band. If you `print(goes_17_data)` and `print(goes_18_data)`, you will find empty collection for `goes_17_data`. According to the data availability of  [GOES 17 dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GOES_17_FDCF), there is no data after 2023-01-10. On the other hand, [GOES 18 dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GOES_18_FDCF) ranges till 2023-08-15.